# Modernizr.mq event triggering multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

So here's the rundown:

- I have a menu that is expanded when the resolution is > 1024
- When the resolution is < 1024 the menu turns into a drop down nav

I use Modernizr.mq to trigger the javascript for the drop down menu when the resolution becomes smaller than 1024.

When you refresh the page and don't resize the browser the menu works fine. But as soon as you resize the browser and try the menu again it bugs out and gets triggered multiple times.

Here's the example in full page view:

http://codepen.io/MarioD/full/aKdhG

And here is the example with the code:

http://codepen.io/MarioD/pen/aKdhG

Any ideas why the click function goes all crazy when the browser is resized? And any way this can be fixed?

Thanks,
Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your adding the click event multiple times - every smartresize because of calling checkMq()

just put the event handler block (`$('.btn-menu').on('click', function(){ ... });`) out of the `checkMq()` function

alternatively u can use `jQuery.one` instead of `jQuery.on` (http://api.jquery.com/one/)

---

btw: you have to wait for the document to be ready. (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
but i guess codepen already handles that.